# How to simplified declaration variable to array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring

How can i simplified this code ? Is a way to do full operation in one line ? Without declaring semestrFrequency in another line

```js
let semestrFrequency = [];
document.querySelectorAll(`tbody tr td:nth-child(5) strong`)
  .forEach((item, index) => semestrFrequency[index] = item.innerText);
```

Comment: Please post the HTML that goes wit it. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: Don't minimize you developement code, a one-liner is just hard to read, it's possible, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```js
const semestrFrequency = [...document.querySelectorAll(`tbody tr td:nth-child(5) strong`)]
  .map(item => item.innerText);

console.log(semestrFrequency)
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5 <strong>Freq 1</strong> freq</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5 <strong>Freq 2</strong> freq</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```